# Windows 11, taskbar corner overflow, show all tray icons

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

In Windows 11 there seem to be no (*standard/user-friendly*) way to set the option of always showing all the tray icons (***Taskbar corner overflow**, as it is now called in Settings*). It only allows you to toggle them one by one:

[image]

Obviously, that is far from ideal.

Is there another way to make all the tray icons to be always visible, so none are hidden, as it was possible to do in Windows 10 and older versions? Perhaps, there is a Registry key that controls this, or a "hidden" shell command to open the "old" settings dialog?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here is a workaround :

- Click the Start or Search icon in the Taskbar
- Type cmd, right-click on Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator
- Copy and paste the following: `explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}`
- Press Enter
- Select "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar"
- Click OK

If the checkbox "Always show all icons ..." is greyed out, I'm not totally sure what fixed it yet but it appears that changing the EnableAutoTray value in the Regedit helped.

To do so, open Regedit, go here:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
```

Then set EnableAutoTray to 1

It seems this needs to be done on every boot so you could create a shortcut on your Desktop using right-click, New, Shortcut and use the command above.

**Update** : at first, I did not like the idea of selecting each app individually using Personalization -> Taskbar -> "Taskbar corner overflow", but in the end, it's not that bad. Whenever there is a new application installed that goes in the overflow, you can use the Personalization setting to add it. It's bit annoying but it works.

**Update 2022** : please see comment from Grx70 below, as he wrote : you can drag and drop the icons that are overflowing by selecting them from the popup and moving them onto the tray bar

Comment: For context, this brings up the older taskbar settings page, according to a page I found just by searching for the CLSID in this answer: https://winaero.com/always-show-tray-icons-windows-10/

Comment: I tried the group policy "Turn off notification area cleanup" and lost all search and taskbar pins.

Comment: You actually don't have to use the Personalization -> Taskbar -> "Taskbar corner overflow" settings page. Simply dragging the icon from the popup onto the tray bar will have the same effect - the switch will be flipped to On in the settings page.

Comment: For me this only opens Quick Access, no oldie settings page.

Comment: MS seems to have nerfed the old settings dialog (opened via shell:::...) in more current Windows 11 releases (tested on 21H2 / WFE 1000.22001.1000.0).
The only option that remains is dragging the icons from the overflow or opening the Settings page setting them visible one-by-one.

Answer (score 17):

My Checkbox for show all was unusable, here's what got it for me on a Windows 10 Home > 11 Home upgrade machine.

Open Regedit, go here:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
```

Look for EnableAutoTray and set the value from 0 to 1

Then run this cmd:

```
explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
```

The check box for showing all items should be interactable.

Comment: This seems to be the ONLY workable method. Both actions need to be taken. And it needs to be re-applied after  EVERY restart of Explorer.exe since Explorer now seems to force the Registry Key back to 0 every time it is (re-)started.

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer seems to be usable at all.  It is now late 2023 and with Windows version 22H2, build 22621.2428, performing this action has no effect.  All system tray icons that are not manually selected to appear are still hidden.

Comment: MS seems to have nerfed the old settings dialog (opened via shell:::...) in more current Windows 11 releases (tested on 21H2 / WFE 1000.22001.1000.0).
The only option that remains is dragging the icons from the overflow or opening the Settings page setting them visible one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

I used a registry diff tool and found out this registry value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings\<uint64>\IsPromoted
```

The value is absent until set in Control Panel. Manually changing it has the expected effect, but good luck with the list of opaque `uint64` numbers… We can automate this, though! I created the script below under GPLv3. [It is on my GitHub with a bit more documentation.](https://github.com/EliseAv/full_tray)

```python
import itertools
import winreg


def main():
    access1 = winreg.KEY_READ
    access2 = winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE | winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE
    key_path = r"Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings"
    super_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, key_path, access=access1)
    for index in itertools.count():
        try:
            name = winreg.EnumKey(super_key, index)
        except OSError:
            break  # no more keys
        subkey = winreg.OpenKey(super_key, name, access=access2)
        examine(name, subkey)
        winreg.CloseKey(subkey)
    winreg.CloseKey(super_key)
    # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
    print(f"Done for {index} keys")


def examine(name, subkey):
    try:
        value, type_ = winreg.QueryValueEx(subkey, "IsPromoted")
        if value == 1 and type_ == winreg.REG_DWORD:
            return  # already correct
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass  # new
    winreg.SetValueEx(subkey, "IsPromoted", 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 1)
    try:
        value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(subkey, "ExecutablePath")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        value = "unknown path"
    print(f"Set IsPromoted=1 for {name} ({value})")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to answer here, but I've implemented this in PowerShell.

[https://gist.github.com/psitem/05d01dfbaa6772b871d0f04262fd8699](https://gist.github.com/psitem/05d01dfbaa6772b871d0f04262fd8699)