# How to show all icons on System Tray in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

After upgrading to windows 11, there is no option available to show all the system tray icons. How do I enable it?

Comment: I can't post it as an answer as I am not going to use WIn11, so I can't verify this.  Try the suggestion son [this page](https://appuals.com/show-all-tray-icons-windows-11/)

Comment: @RohitGupta - Why exactly can’t you submit an answer to a non-protected question? Only reason would be an answer ban.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 11, taskbar corner overflow, show all tray icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1680130/windows-11-taskbar-corner-overflow-show-all-tray-icons)

Comment: @Ramhound , because I  wouldn't be talking from experience or from a verified stance. If that was a link to Microsoft, I  could have posted it.